# profile page url like facebook profile -php

Tags: php, facebook, .htaccess, url-rewriting, profile

Could anyone please help me to use .htaccess file to customize the profile page url like facebook profiles and some other social networking sites like twitter .

For all the users who are logged into my website the url is www.mywebsite.com/view/profile. But I want to change that url to www.mywebsite.com/username.

Is there any other option other than .htaccess to customize profile link?

Comment: if you are using any frameworks then you can change to this by using route functionality

Comment: If you are on Apache and have `mod_rewrite` available, then you can write a rule for each username in `.htaccess`.

Comment: how it is possible. I`m new to .htacess.Could you please guide me to write .htaccess file

Comment: I suggest you do some study on `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess`, you'll get an idea.

Comment: `mod_rewrite` is best for your solution. @rms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check this out:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)|([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))$ ./profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

You can copy the above code and paste it on your .htaccess file.
The profile.php is your php file that will read the username.
You can check it out by creating a profile.php and use

```
var_dump($_GET); die();
```

and you will see the variable $_GET['username']
and from there you can now query your sql. 
* Just be careful for the sql injection and add some security.

Comment: check your mod_rewrite if is it enable.

Answer (score 0):

You have a website with the name example.com and you want to redirect all incoming urls that are going to example.com/ to example.com/profile.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/profile.php [L,R=301]
```

This way you can check in you profile page if the request have some restricted keywords like http://example.com/accout or http://example.com/settings etc then redirect to that page where you can handle the operation or else display the profile of the user
like http://example.com/rms

Comment: Please read about .htaccess , or else you wont be able to figure out the rewrite rules , Common usage of rewrite can be found here [link](https://my.hostmonster.com/cgi/help/htaccess_redirect)

Answer (score -1):

You can learn more about **`.htaccess`** at:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html